# Proving $f'(c) = 0$ using the property of differentiability and local maximum

Tags: real-analysis, limits

It is given that,

$f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and $c\in I$. The function $f$ is said to have a *local maximum* at $c$ if and only if there is a $\delta >0$ such that $f\left( c\right) \geq f\left( x\right)$ holds for all $\left| x-c\right| <\delta$.

First have to prove,

$\dfrac {f\left( u+c\right) -f\left(c\right)} {u}\leq 0$ for $u>0$ and

$\dfrac {f\left( t+c\right) -f\left(c\right)} {t}\geq 0$ for $t<0$.

Approach:

Let $h\in(0,\delta)$

Then, $0 < h < \delta \rightarrow h+c<\delta + c$

so, $h+c$ lies in the given neighbourhood - $x\in(c-\delta, c+\delta)$

by letting $x=c+h = u$

$f(c) \geq f(x) \rightarrow f(c+h) - f(c) \leq 0 $

As $c+h = u > 0 $,

$\dfrac{f(u) - f(c)}{u} \leq 0 $

Did the same for the other part by choosing $c-h = t$. Then used side limits and proved the differentiability.

Can anyone give an idea for the analogous result, local minima as well?

Comment: If $f$ has a local minimum at $c$ then $-f$ has a local maximum at $c$.

Comment: @geetha290krm ah yeah that would work. By the way is my approach correct?

Comment: Do you assume that $f'(c)$ exists? Or do you want to prove that it exists and to show that is $0$?

Comment: @PaulFrost it is given that $f'(c)$ exists for the latter part

Comment: You should add this information to your question.